# Binary column SELECT with LIKE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, binary, hex, sql-like

I'm trying to find specific lines of data from a `BINARY` column.

Example data in the `BINARY(2000)` column:

```
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
```

This data has 1 result of `2201` somewhere in it. (try searching the data for 2201 and you will get 1.)

Now I'm trying to use this query: (it should give me 512 rows of results)

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE binaryfield LIKE '%2201%'
ORDER BY key
```

But no luck in getting results.

Notes: 2201 actually is 290. I'm trying to look for the decimal value 290 which is 2201 in hex in the data that is in endian.

**Update:**

Tried this query (searching for: 15584)

```
SELECT *
FROM CHAR_DATA1
WHERE CHAR_DATA LIKE '%'+CAST(0xE03C AS nvarchar(MAX))+'%'
ORDER BY CHAR_KEY;
```

Now its returning almost all rows. Even manually checked the rows for E03C but none was found, but when running the query it gets returned. very odd. ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) operator only works on character data types. Try doing a [CAST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to a string, like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table
 WHERE CAST(binaryfield AS nvarchar(MAX)) LIKE '%290%'
 ORDER BY key;
```

-- or --

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table
 WHERE CAST(binaryfield AS nvarchar(MAX)) LIKE '%'+CAST(0x2201 AS nvarchar(MAX))+'%'
 ORDER BY key;
```

Also, if you want to look at a subset of the data (e.g. the file header), you can do something like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table
 WHERE CAST(LEFT(binaryfield, 8) AS nvarchar(MAX)) -- Only compares the first 8 bytes
         LIKE '%'+CAST(0x2201 AS nvarchar(MAX))+'%'
    OR CAST(SUBSTRING(binaryfield, 34, 4) AS nvarchar(MAX)) -- Compares bytes 34-38
         LIKE '%'+CAST(0x2201 AS nvarchar(MAX))+'%'
 ORDER BY key;
```

---

**Edit**

Regarding your updated question, does this give you the results that you're expecting:

```
 SELECT *
   FROM CHAR_DATA1
  WHERE CHAR_DATA COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
          LIKE '%'+CAST(0xE03C AS nvarchar(MAX))+'%'
 ORDER BY CHAR_KEY;
```

You shouldn't have to cast/convert the character data to binary.

Comment: Hello, tried this and it returned no results. I updated my question for the info on the column. THanks :)

Comment: Tried a few variations based on your query, it gave me results but the wrong once.

Comment: I tried your second query, it kinda works but returns more rows of results than it should. hmmm? gives 2000+, the correct should only be 512 results. but in the 2000+ results its giving, the 512 correct one is in it.

Comment: That's odd, perhaps that character is in some of the other rows as well. The LIKE operator is essentially checking for `'%Ģ%'` - you can verify this be running the following: `SELECT '''%'+CAST(0x2201 AS nvarchar(MAX))+'%'''`

Comment: Edited my question. Can you please check? Thanks.

Comment: The latest edit: Expression type binary is invalid for COLLATE clause.

Comment: Okay, I tried the same query as the last time where I'm getting results. And changed the hex to another SELECT *
FROM CHAR_DATA1
WHERE CHAR_DATA
 LIKE '%'+CAST(0xE03C AS nvarchar(MAX))+'%'
ORDER BY CHAR_KEY; <- now this too gives all rows.

Comment: Is the `CHAR_DATA` column, not defined as nvarchar data type? Explicitly using a [Collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx) on a text data type should not be an issue. Although, if the `CHAR_DATA` column is binary, then CAST it to nvarchar first.

Comment: Well, I don't see anything wrong with the query based upon my understanding of the schema & data so far. What is it that you're trying to accomplish? I can't imaging why you'd need to search a bunch of binary data for a single, specific byte of data that could be anywhere in the file. Perhaps, narrowing the search down to a subset of the bytes (e.g. bytes 0-24) would yield more accurate results.

Comment: This binary contains alot of data about something, like name, some numbers, some other text. I have to find if a set of number is seen in the data, so I can say that this persons data has this number. And narrowing it with subset wont work because the data should be found on different parts not only specific parts. Thanks though :)

Comment: I'm guessing that this is data that has been serialized into a database. If that's correct, and if it's possible, I'd suggest [normalizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) the data in your database so that you can write a standard query to get your data (e.g. `WHERE PhoneNumber LIKE '123456%'`).

Comment: There is nothing I can do about this, beacuse the application is hard coded with it reading from serialized data